# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS under Hyper-V brings me to an XRDP login window that then proceeds to a blank screen

Tags: 22.04, windows, hyper-v

novice user here

I am using Hyper-V in Windows and installed the Ubuntu image with no problems through the system.  However, upon bootup, I am faced with an XRDP login window with some Xorg option selected.  When I enter my username and password, it simply goes to a teal background and it's frozen.  Nothing can be clicked or selected

Kind of a huge problem to have with the software, why is this not addressed by default?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the VM menu click View and uncheck Enhanced Session. That will return you to the regular Ubuntu login for a username and password you created during the installation. With RDP login you get full-screen Ubuntu and drive and clipboard sharing which are otherwise difficult to set up.